# can django ORM handle conditional mysql statements

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I need to write following query

```
SELECT id, name, (

                     CASE WHEN photo =  ''
                     THEN  'DEFAULT_PIC'
                     ELSE photo
                     END
                  ) AS image
       FROM admin_category
```

Can ORM handle it ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done in model.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def image(self):
        return self.photo or u'DEFAULT_PIC'

# usage
category.image
```

Comment: can you explain what the `@property` is?

Comment: @starcorn Docs can do it [much better](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) than me. Here it is just a way to follow the convention of Django model fields: atrributes, not methods.